# how to get and install go package io/ioutil

Tags: go, get

I want to read from a file using ioutil. When I run the program I get the message "..\io\ioutil\ioutil.go:9:2: cannot find package "." in: C:\go\src\bytes". I assume I don't have the package io/ioutil. I tried using go get ioutil, and I get the message "..\io\ioutil\ioutil.go:9:2: package bytes is not in GOROOT (c:\go\src\bytes)". How do I overcome this? I'm using windows command prompt.

Comment: `io/ioutil` is a Go standard library package. You needn't install it. I suggest you follow the Windows installation instructions here: https://golang.org/doc/install and then the rest of the tutorial once you've installed Go

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you post the code where you are seeing the error. My first guess, without looking at the code, is that you are missing the import statement to tell Go that you want to use this package: `import "io/ioutil"`

Comment: I do have the  import "io/ioutil" statement there. I have other standard library packages with no problem, such as fmt, string, strconv.

Comment: I basicly copied sample code from a website, thus:

Comment: package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
 "bufio"
)

func main() {

func main() {  
  f, err := os.Open("test.txt")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer func() {
    if err = f.Close(); err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }()
  r := bufio.NewReader(f)
  b := make([]byte, 3)
  for {
    n, err := r.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error reading file:", err)
      break
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b[0:n]))
  }

}   //.... the same happens with bufio as with io/ioutil.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a file `sample.go` and it compiles with no problems for me:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    f, err := os.Open("test.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err = f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    b := make([]byte, 3)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading file:", err)
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b[0:n]))
    }
}
```

```
$ go build sample.go
```

There were two definitions of `func main()` in your code but I wasn't sure if that was a paste and cut error or if you indeed have duplicated in your code.

Comment: That was just a minor cut and paste error.

Comment: I reinstalled go, and it now works. Wasn't a bad idea anyway, as I had an older version.